# django/wagtail makemigrations does not work once apps move to custom folder

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am new to Django/wagtail project, wants to change the project structure by putting all the apps inside custom apps folder and inside the module-specific (projects) folder as I need to merge 3 different applications, here is the image of my new structure .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTdbt.png)

here common folder contains apps which are common to all 3 projects

I am trying  to run makemigrations and migrate which is not giving any out put , I also tried putting **init**.py and models.py inside common and apps folder to treat as package (which I don't want) ,still no results

can someone help me out  with my new structure ,am I doing anything wrong ?

I tried to run the single app by makemigrations appname, but no results, here is the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MruQK.jpg)

one more question how can I run makemigrations for all three apps without running for each and every app, the reason is  in the real project I have already more than 30 apps developed, so Is there any other way to run once

Answer (score 2):

When you first run `makemigrations`, be sure to specify the name of your app:

```
python manage.py makemigrations settings
```

And then do each app in turn.  You might also have to create a `migrations` folder within the app.

Comment: Thanks @Dan , could you please look into the above edit comment

Comment: you also might need to clean the migration tables in your db.

Comment: @Clarity After clean and recreate DB , it only migrate project/root level apps, not inside the common folder apps, any Idea how to migrate apps inside common folder?

Comment: Are you saying that after you cleaned and recreated the DB and ran `makemigrations`, that it didn't even generate any migrations?

Comment: I've found that you sometimes have to create the `migrations` folder before it will create the migrations - not sure why.

Comment: Yeah , It works fine now, there was some problem in the cleaning of DB , Thanks @DanSwain

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps of above problem
1. Clean the DB 
     ( one approach - delete local SQLite file followed by migrations files inside each app/migrations folder except **init**.py )

2. Rerun makemigrations , migrate , you can see all yours migrations file  or you can use showmigrations to see each apps migrations created or not.
3. creatsuperuser again